# How to fetch the price of a token(off-chain) based on token name/symbol/address

Tags: token, spl-token-program, price

I'm building a client that acts as a wallet portfolio application. I'm wondering if there's a way for me to fetch the price of a token, based on its name/symbol/address? [image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "price"?

Comment: Price of the token (e.g BTC, ETH, SOL) in USD @sohrab

Comment: this screenshot doesn't seem relevant to the question (whether it's the current output of your client or not). please replace it with some code and annotate where in the code you would anticipate using the new functionality

Answer (score 3):

The name, symbol, coingecko id you are getting might not match the expected coingecko_id by coingecko. Regardless of the origin of this data (legacy token list, on-chain...).

You can query the token price directly from the token mint, example for SLRS:

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/token_price/solana?vs_currencies=usd&contract_addresses=SLRSSpSLUTP7okbCUBYStWCo1vUgyt775faPqz8HUMr

This resolves to a single source of truth, coingecko

Answer (score 0):

I understand Solana Explorer uses CoinGecko for its market price data.

They have a [REST API](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation) with a free tier (50 calls/min). `/coins/list` gets you the list of available tokens and `/coins/{your coin ID}` will give you details like price, market cap, etc.

There are some unofficial clients that wrap this API, including [coingecko-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coingecko-api) (which Solana Explorer uses) but it hasn't been updated for 3 years so I would stick with calling the REST API directly.

Here is an example of calling the REST API to get the USD price of Solana:

```
λ curl --silent 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/solana?tickers=false&market_data=true&community_data=false&developer_data=false&sparkline=false' | jq .market_data.current_price.usd
36.65
```